# Can I flush W3TC's cache in a capistrano deploy?

Tags: plugin-w3-total-cache, deployment

I'm trying to simplify my deploy process and am making use of the Capistrano tool.  Is there a way to have capistrano flush W3TC's cache in a deploy task?

Answer (score 3):

As @andreascreten, [wp-cli](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli) will do the job for you.

wp-cli includes commands for W3TC (located in the `src/php/wp-cli/commands/community/total-cache.php` file), so you can flush the cache by running:

```
$ wp total-cache flush <type>
```

Where `<type>` is one of 'db', 'minify', 'object', 'page' or 'post'.

(Note: If you use 'post', you'll need to pass in `--post_id=` or `--permalink=` as well)

Answer (score 0):

You could use wp-cli to flush W3TC: https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli.

Comment: Can you provide a better explanation here instead of just a link?